# how to put font awesome class in an array where there already is a bootstrap button class

Tags: php, laravel, bootstrap-4, font-awesome

So this is my code for delete action in my webpage

```
{!!Form::open(['action' => ['PostsController@destroy', $post->id],'method'=>'POST', 'class' => 'float-right'])!!} 
{{Form::hidden('_method','DELETE')}}
{{Form::submit('Delete',['class' => 'btn btn-danger'])}}
{!!Form::close()!!}
```

now I want to put this `<i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i>` font awesome icon in that button before the 'delete' text
So, how do I get this thing to happen, Help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Do manually using:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">
    <i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i> Delete
</button>
```

Or in Blade use:

```
{!! Form::button( '<i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i> Delete', ['class'=>'btn btn-danger','type'=>'submit'] ) !!}
```

Comment: it didnt work . the icon didnt show, it show the markup instead